Excel adding filename to formula when creating duplicate file copy
I have regular issues when creating copies of a file, where the formulas will seemingly randomly decide to reference the original file, rather than the Sheet and Cell within the new file.
I use a Project_Details tab/worksheet in excel to contain header information and general info for a project.  eg, Customer name and address, and Estimated Project Value or other figures I will use in calculations in multiple places in different tabs/worksheets throughout the workbook/file.
As these files are passed around a team, and also submitted to managers for comments, I always create a back-up copy of the file prior to emailing.  However, this will occasionally and seemingly randomly update the reference formulas from  (for example):

'Project_Details'!$C$12

to

'[c:\documents\Proj_1234-Client_ABC-rev1]Project_Details'!$C$12

How do I stop this?  Can I force Excel to not do this without having to Find and Replace file names in every copy of the file?
